# how do i break a for loop in python?

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to make a program that takes your input of a number and prints out the numbers below it all the way to 1. after that i want it to count up again to the original number. example with 5:

```
5
4
3
2
1
2
3
4
5
```

here's the code:

```
tall1 = int(input("skriv inn tall her: "))



def hundreTilEn(tall):
    while True:
        if tall != 1:
            tall = tall - 1
            print(tall)
        else:
            print(tall)
            break
        if tall == 1:
            for tall in range(tall1):
                print(tall)
                if tall == tall1:
                    print(tall)
                    break

hundreTilEn(tall1)
```

it doesnt want to stop counting, example with 5:

```
4
3
2
1
0
1
2
3
4
3
2
1
0...
```

Comment: Do it with two `for-in-range` loops? Do you have to use `while`?

Comment: Your conditions read like "if it's not one", "if it's not *not* one" and "if it is somehow one despite already having called `break` earlier when it was one".

Comment: You should use a different variable when you're incrementing and decrementing. You need to save the original value of `tall` so you can compare with it when counting up.

Comment: @tadman Not sure what your point is, but it sounds like you misread it.

Comment: Apparently there's a "no loops" solution. Would love to see that

Comment: @DarkKnight [What I had in mind](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PyU1TSGjNC@lKDUkM8c1T6MkMSdH04pLAQgKijLzSiACYH5mmgKIo2CnYAhRAALoehV0FQw14bLIRnAhKzXV/P8fAA).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `abs()` method to make this more simple:

```
val = int(input("Enter: "))
for i in range(-val, val + 1):
    print(abs(i))
```

This doubles the iteration required (given it needs to include negatives) and ensures the values are always positive.

Comment: Although actually they only want to go down to 1, not 0. Easy to adjust, though.

Answer (score 0):

My solution employs 2 loops, 1 count down, and 1 count up:

```py
def hundreTilEn(tall):
    for i in range(tall, 1, -1):
        print(i)

    for i in range(1, tall + 1):
        print(i)
```

The first loop will print 5, 4, 3, 2; and the second will print 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.